# how to remove undefined variable name in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

i make a form in symfony and in controller i get the post values but when i get values if variable not exist it shows undefined variable,here is my controller:

```
 for($i=1; $i<=$itemscounter; $i++){

                    if($i==1){
                        $items = $_POST['items'];
                        $description=$_POST['description'];
                        $unitprice=$_POST['unitprice'];
                        $quantity=$_POST['quantity'];
                        $linetotal=$_POST['linetotal']; 


                    }else {
                        $items = $_POST['items'.$i];
                        $description=$_POST['description'.$i];
                        $unitprice=$_POST['unitprice'.$i];
                        $quantity=$_POST['quantity'.$i];
                        $linetotal=$_POST['linetotal'.$i];                      
                    }

                    $entity->setInvoiceid($invoiceid);
                    $entity->setInvoiceitemsid($items);
                    $entity->setDescription($description);
                    $entity->setUnitPrice($unitprice);
                    $entity->setQuantity($quantity);
                    $entity->setlinetotal($linetotal);
                    $em->persist($entity);                        
                    $em->flush();
                    $em->clear();

                }
            }else{

                    $items = $_POST['items'];
                    $description=$_POST['description'];
                    $unitprice=$_POST['unitprice'];
                    $quantity=$_POST['quantity'];
                    $linetotal=$_POST['linetotal']; 
                    $entity->setInvoiceid($invoiceid);
                    $entity->setInvoiceitemsid($items);
                    $entity->setDescription($description);
                    $entity->setUnitPrice($unitprice);
                    $entity->setQuantity($quantity);
                    $entity->setlinetotal($linetotal);
                    $em->persist($entity);                        
                    $em->flush();
                    $em->clear();
                }
```

but when controller get values items2,description2,unitprice2,quantity2,linetotal2 does not exist how to remove this error?when it gets value if items2 not post then it store no value in items,my itemscounter value is 6.

Comment: Are you using `$form->handleRequest($request)`?

Comment: no i don't use $form->handleRequest($request)

Comment: It would do most of the work for you. I would recommend looking into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you should use basic php like [isset](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.isset.php).
But i guess it's more a problem of the logic of your code. you should use html names like items[1](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.isset.php)[description], it's so easy to use.

I cleaned a bit your code. You shouldn't use copy pasta

```
for($i=1; $i<=$itemscounter; $i++){

    if($i==1){
        $suffix= '';
    }else{
        $suffix = $i;
    }

    if( isset($_POST['items'.$suffix])
        && isset($_POST['description'.$suffix]) 
        ......) {

        $items = $_POST['items'.$suffix];
        $description=$_POST['description'.$suffix];
        $unitprice=$_POST['unitprice'.$suffix];
        $quantity=$_POST['quantity'.$suffix];
        $linetotal=$_POST['linetotal'.$suffix];                      


        $entity->setInvoiceid($invoiceid);
        $entity->setInvoiceitemsid($items);
        $entity->setDescription($description);
        $entity->setUnitPrice($unitprice);
        $entity->setQuantity($quantity);
        $entity->setlinetotal($linetotal);
        $em->persist($entity);                        
        $em->flush();
        $em->clear();

}
```